# Curl request doesn't work when referring a secret variable in azuredevops

Tags: bash, curl, azure-devops

I'm developing an shell script that will create work items in a pipeline.

It reads from a file(file.txt) a title for the work item, then creates work items in the project using the azuredevops api.

Example of file.txt content:

```
CWE-113: Improper Neutralization of CRLF Sequences in HTTP Headers ('HTTP Response Splitting'): com/veracode/verademo/controller/UserController.java:713
CWE-117: Improper Output Neutralization for Logs: com/veracode/verademo/controller/UserController.java:803
CWE-117: Improper Output Neutralization for Logs: com/veracode/verademo/controller/UserController.java:859
CWE-73: External Control of File Name or Path: com/veracode/verademo/controller/UserController.java:863
CWE-327: Use of a Broken or Risky Cryptographic Algorithm: com/veracode/verademo/controller/UserController.java:961
```

Here's my script, that is executed in an yaml pipeline in AzurePipelines:

```
while read -r line; do
              echo -------------------------Start Request to Create Work Item-------------------
             
              curl -i --location --request POST 'https://dev.azure.com/myorg/myproject/_apis/wit/workitems/$Task?api-version=6.0' \
              --header 'Content-Type: application/json-patch+json' \
              --header "Authorization: $MYAUT" \
              --verbose \
              --data-raw '[{"op":"add","path":"/fields/System.Title","value":"'"$line"'"}]'
 
      done < file.txt
```

The variable '$MYAUTH' is the Base64 encoded PAT used to authenticate, and is supposed to be stored in the **Library** tab of AzurePipelines as a secret.

$MYAUTH content example

```
BASIC 123S8A29389
```

The issue I'm facing is that when the variable '$MYAUTH' is set to secret(in Library), the script doesn't work, with the following response:

```
HTTP/2 411 
content-type: text/html; charset=us-ascii
date: Tue, 10 Aug 2021 20:27:13 GMT
content-length: 344

<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN""http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<HTML><HEAD><TITLE>Length Required</TITLE>
<META HTTP-EQUIV="Content-Type" Content="text/html; charset=us-ascii"></HEAD>
<BODY><h2>Length Required</h2>
<hr><p>HTTP Error 411. The request must be chunked or have a content length.</p>
</BODY></HTML>
/opt/myagent/_work/_temp/dasddaswq.sh: line 34: --header: command not found
```

The line 34 in this case is the line that the $MYAUTH variable is in.
When the variable is not set to secret in Library, the script works as intended.

Comment: The error `line 34: --header: command not found` indicates that line 34 is being treated as a separate command, rather than a continuation of the `curl` command. There may be something wrong in the precise formatting of the script (e.g. something like a space after the `\` that's supposed to be at the end of a line), but it's hard to say without examining the exact file in detail.

Comment: How are you mapping the secret into your script's environment? Show your pipeline.

Comment: The variable is being mapped directly from the library section of AzurePipelines, it's is a variable group. I can refer it can from the bash script using $VARIABLE https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml%2Cbatch

Comment: @GordonDavisson, what exactly do you need? The script file is included in the post, as well as the variable format

Comment: @RicardoLima I don't see anything in the post that'd explain it, so I think *something* is different from what's actually being run. Try adding the `set -x` command before the problematic bit. That'll make it print an execution trace as it runs, so you can better see what the shell thinks is happening (note: it'll add single-quotes around anything like command arguments that contains weird characters -- don't get confused by the quotes, but what's *in* them might be informative).

Comment: If mapping in the variable group didn't work - have you tried to map in the `env` block of your bash task? That's the recommended way. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml%2Cbatch#secret-variables